# change directory error with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal, directory, cd

I started going through The Command Line Crash Course by Zed Shaw and I'm in the Change Directory lesson.  When I type in `cd../../ pwd` an error comes up:

`the term cd is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program`

I'm not sure what this means and also in this context.  I know I typed in something it doesn't recognize but it seems like this is something it is supposed to recognize.  My current theory is that it is reading into a blank space but that's not what the error message reads.  So I am a little lost.

Thanks.

Comment: Sidenote: Be aware that "The Command Line Crash Course" makes use of a lot of *aliases* in powershell to ease the experience from cmd/terminal. `cd` and `pwd` are not actual commands in PowerShell, but aliases for the `Set-Location` and `Get-Location` cmdlets respectively. You can type in `Get-Alias` and press enter to retrieve all aliases (the output will show their definitions as well)

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try those out.

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing a space between `cd` and `../../`?

Also `pwd` is a separate command and should be entered separately after you run `cd`

```
cd ../../      # this changes the current working directory to its parent's parent (goes up two levels)
pwd            # this displays the current working directory (the original directory's parent's parent)
```

So for example:

```
C:\users\you\dir1\dir2\dir3> cd ../../
C:\users\you\dir1> pwd
C:\users\you\dir1
C:\users\you\dir1>
```

Comment: Thanks! The spacing thing was what was causing the trouble.  Next time I get an error like this I'll check for spacing as well.